# Верстка разных по ширине картинок

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.
Есть кусок верстки.

```
<div class="col-md-7">
                <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 25px;"><span
                        style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 36px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;">ПО ШИРИНЕ</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div style="padding-bottom: 32px; padding-top: 52px; text-align: center;"><span class="size_product"
                            style="text-align: center; color: #000000;  font-family: arial, sans-serif;">280 <span
                            style="font-size: 24px;">ММ</span></span></div>
                    <img src="image/fifth/wood_bottom_1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div style="padding-bottom: 32px; padding-top: 52px; text-align: center;"><span class="size_product"
                            style="text-align: center; color: #000000;  font-family: arial, sans-serif;">200 <span
                            style="font-size: 24px;">ММ</span></span></div>
                    <img src="image/fifth/wood_bottom_2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div style="padding-bottom: 32px; padding-top: 52px; text-align: center;"><span class="size_product"
                            style="text-align: center; color: #000000;  font-family: arial, sans-serif;">180 <span
                            style="font-size: 24px;">ММ</span></span></div>
                    <img src="image/fifth/wood_bottom_3.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div style="padding-bottom: 32px; padding-top: 52px; text-align: center;"><span class="size_product"
                            style="text-align: center; color: #000000;  font-family: arial, sans-serif;">150 <span
                            style="font-size: 24px;">ММ</span></span></div>
                    <img src="image/fifth/wood_bottom_4.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div style="padding-bottom: 32px; padding-top: 52px; text-align: center;"><span class="size_product"
                            style="text-align: center; color: #000000;  font-family: arial, sans-serif;">120 <span
                            style="font-size: 24px;">ММ</span></span></div>
                    <img src="image/fifth/wood_bottom_5.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
```

5 картинок: 1 жирная 2 средних 2 маленьких.
При низких разрешениях картинки не входят по ширине в блоки, картинки слишком широкие.
Делал у картинок `width:100%` В ширину все хорошо тогда, но в высоту при этом картинки становятся разные.

Comment: какие размеры у картинок, ширины блоков и т. п. надо себе представить самостоятельно?

Comment: При разных разрешениях она разная, что у блока что у картинки, - при низких разрешениях (меньше 1400) ширина картинки больше блока. На ширине 1366 - 185 и 165px

Comment: Если вы делали `width: 100%`, картинки при этом сжимались и становились разной высоты, то это значит, что и без сжатия они разной высоты, так? Ведь уменьшение ширины пропорционально уменьшает высоту, не нарушая соотношение сторон.

Comment: В этом то и проблема, картинки в исходном состоянии (183х538, 131х538, 131х538, 120х538, 120х538), если я делаю width:100%, они по ширине сжались в ширину блока (у блоков ширина разная) ивысоты картинок стали разные.

Comment: значит, раз уж у вас одинаковая высота при разной ширине, вам надо подобрать такое значение высоты, при котором всё будет ок. как-то так: `@media (max-width: 1366px) { img { height: 400px; } }`

Comment: Спасибо за совет, пошел ковырять - надеюсь на качестве картинки сильно это не отразится.